# How to exclude classes from an eclipse project

Tags: eclipse

How can i exclude some classes from my eclipse project?the thing is that i make some major changes and i can't run the whole project without correcting it.But i want to test it up to the point i've fixed it.

Comment: How you mean exclude: that you do not compile them, do not refer them or what?

Comment: Well either one what i want is that my project compiles and is able to run properly even though there are errors in classes that in my test-run won't be used

Comment: Maybe if you change their names you will achieve what you want

Comment: well it won't compile as long as a class contains errors..

Comment: I meant change the extensions. In that way the files will not be compiled

Comment: ooh i get it now but is there any other way this one seems a bit hackie

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Select the files that you want to exclude from the build. `Right click` -> `Build path` -> `exclude`.

You can readd them later with `Right click` -> `Build path` -> `include`.

As already mentioned you can achieve the same via file extension change.

Answer (score 1):

from 2023, right click the file, select properties, select or dis-select “exclude resource from build". This is for the latest Eclipse IDE in 2023 version. There are a lot of changes since 2012.